# How to save Array of Integers in SQL database?

Tags: java, json, sqlite

I have a problem with declaration with one of my fields in Object.

```
public class PhotoEntity {

   @SerializedName("mentions")
   public Array<Integer> mentions = new ArrayList<>();

   // Other fields
}
```

**mentions** - is a part of incoming JSON, looks like :

```
[120,55,32]
```

I have a question. How correctly make projection of ArrayList in SQL database?

---

*In the best case, as I know - I need to create separate Table and setup foreign key, but in my case it not be applicable, because the structure of `PhotoEntity` directly related to JSON contract.*

Comment: Depends: Which DBMS are you using? Most have a JSON format nowadays, so just push it in there as JSON especially if you do not need to use it in database queries.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen SqlLiteDatabase

Comment: That one needs a separate extension (see https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html), so if you do not query the data at all then just use a varchar to dump it in (watch for maximum length of your data ofcourse), and let the application on load of the data parse it as a json again.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen and after that use in runtime as `ArrayList<Integer>`?I mean i need to create separate method like an `ArrayList<Integer> getMentions()` which convert JSON data to ArrayList and returns to me?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen in this case i can just replace `ArrayList` to String.

Comment: Quick way for conversion: Look at GSON. Works like a charm.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I already used it :)